# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre Invoke y un llamado normal en C#?

Tags: c#, sintaxis, delegados

Estoy trabajando en C# y me surgió una pequeña duda.

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre llamar a un delegado de modo directo o usar el método `Invoke`?

Por ejemplo:

```
Func<string> @Func = () => "Test";
var result = @Func.Invoke(); 
var result2 = @Func(); 
Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}",result,result2); 
// El resultado es Test,Test
```

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre la línea `@Func.Invoke();` y `@Func();`?

En caso de existir tal diferencia, ¿en qué casos debería usarse cada uno?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En estos casos, lo mejor es ver que hace el compilador cuando convierte el código a IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldsfld      UserQuery.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
IL_0006:  brtrue.s    IL_001B
IL_0008:  ldnull      
IL_0009:  ldftn       b__0
IL_000F:  newobj      System.Func<System.String>..ctor
IL_0014:  stsfld      UserQuery.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
IL_0019:  br.s        IL_001B
IL_001B:  ldsfld      UserQuery.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1
IL_0020:  stloc.0     // Func
IL_0021:  ldloc.0     // Func
IL_0022:  callvirt    System.Func<System.String>.Invoke
IL_0027:  stloc.1     // result
IL_0028:  ldloc.0     // Func
IL_0029:  callvirt    System.Func<System.String>.Invoke
IL_002E:  stloc.2     // result2
IL_002F:  ldstr       "{0},{1}"
IL_0034:  ldloc.1     // result
IL_0035:  ldloc.2     // result2
IL_0036:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_003B:  nop         
IL_003C:  ret
```

Como puedes ver, el IL de `@Func.Invoke()` es exactamente el mismo que el de `@Func()`:

```
callvirt    System.Func<System.String>.Invoke
```

Así que ambos son exactamente idénticos.

Comment: como haces para visualizar IL?

Comment: @Byron2017 normalmente uso la aplicación [LinqPAD](https://www.linqpad.net/) que permite escribir programas y ver su salida en IL entre otras cosas

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaria veas

[Func() vs Func.Invoke()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309286/funct-vs-funct-invoke)

Alli se hace una refencia a una respuesta interesante de la cual extraigo

Llamar al metodo directo

> If you directly call a method then the compiler will generate the necessary code to look up the method start address in the object's virtual table.
>   The runtime is ultimately responsible for dealing with this because a vtable can change depending on the object being used.  Highly optimized and very fast given modern processors.  This is the ideal mechanism to use.  The problem is that you must know at compilation time the type being referenced, the method name and its signature.  This is formally known as early binding.  If the method information changes then your code won't compile.

Traduccion

> Si llama directamente a un método, el compilador generará el código necesario para buscar la dirección de inicio del método en la tabla virtual del objeto.
>   El tiempo de ejecución es el responsable final de lidiar con esto porque una vtable puede cambiar dependiendo del objeto que se esté utilizando. Procesadores modernos altamente optimizados y muy rápidos dados. Este es el mecanismo ideal para usar. El problema es que debe saber en el momento de la compilación el tipo de referencia, el nombre del método y su firma. Esto se conoce formalmente como unión temprana. Si la información del método cambia, entonces su código no se compilará.

Usando Invoke

> Invoke is a late binding technique where you postpone determining a method name and signature until you are actually ready to call it.  This is primarily used when you dynamically load assemblies and types and want to be able to call methods on the types.  You can't use early binding because the types were not available during compilation.

Traduccion

> Invoke es una técnica de enlace tardío en la que pospones la determinación del nombre y la firma de un método hasta que realmente estás listo para llamarlo. Esto se usa principalmente cuando se cargan dinámicamente conjuntos y tipos y desea poder llamar a métodos en los tipos. No puede utilizar el enlace temprano porque los tipos no estaban disponibles durante la compilación.

Comment: Hmm, creo que discrepo con la respuesta original. No se si tal vez en versiones iniciales de .net esto era asi, pero como puedes ver en mi respuesta, el código IL generado es idéntico en ambos casos, asi que creo que no hay absolutamente ninguna diferencia.

Comment: Por cierto, parece que el señor Skeet está de acuerdo conmigo, la respuesta que enlazas habla de otra cosa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309286/funct-vs-funct-invoke#comment30751879_16309331